# Blue screen and Auto Reboot

Tags: windows-7, drivers, troubleshooting

Hello Everyone,
                                 I  am facing the bluesceen problem on Window 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit, I am sharing the Zip file with few memory dumps. 
http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g74a24d3e9d210a3d99918718672871cbd48bdf1d3

I have already checked the below items

Check the temperature via “CoreTemp” tool : Result : Good
Check the RAM  via “MeMTest” tool : Result : Good
Check the Harddisk  via “Western digital data life guard” tool : Result : Good

Can you please help me to find out the root cause(which driver/hardware/software creating this problem)  of Blue screen.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Gaurav

Answer (score 2):

All dumps show you have storage issues:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff88004c40000, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80001683040, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!RtlCopyMemoryNonTemporal+40
fffff800`01683040 4c8b0c11        mov     r9,qword ptr [rcx+rdx]

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT_SERVER

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  sqlservr.exe

STACK_TEXT:     
nt!KeBugCheckEx
nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
nt!KiPageFault
nt!RtlCopyMemoryNonTemporal
hal!HalpDmaSyncMapBuffers
hal!HalpDmaMapScatterTransfer
hal!HalpMapTransfer
hal!IoMapTransfer
hal!HalpAllocateAdapterCallback
hal!HalAllocateAdapterChannel
hal!HalBuildScatterGatherList
PCIIDEX!BmSetup
ataport!IdeDispatchChannelRequest
ataport!IdeStartChannelRequest
ataport!IdeStartDeviceRequest
ataport!IdePortPdoDispatch
ataport!IdePortDispatch
CLASSPNP!ServiceTransferRequest
CLASSPNP!ClassReadWrite
partmgr!PmGlobalDispatch
volmgrx!VMX_IO_DISK_EXTENT::Transfer
volmgrx!VmxpMirrorWritePhase1
volmgrx!VMX_OVERLAPPED_IO_MANAGER::AcquireIoRegion
volmgrx!VMX_IO_MIRROR::LaunchWrite
volmgrx!VMX_IO_MIRROR::Transfer
volmgrx!VmxReadWrite
volmgr!VmReadWrite
volsnap!VolsnapWriteFilter
Ntfs!NtfsStorageDriverCallout
nt!KxSwitchKernelStackCallout
nt!KiSwitchKernelStackContinue
```

Ran chkdsk /r /f and try different cables. Also update the bIOS from 2.1a to 2.1c.

Comment: agree completely. also, leave SMART active so you can track possible future problems.